# Why does the power in an inductor equal what it does?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, power, differentiation, inductance

I understand that power is that rate at which work is done and that because of this the power in an inductor is equal to 
$$P=\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac12Li^2\right).$$ 
I also understand that the power is also equal to
 $$P=Li\frac{di}{dt}$$
since $L\,\frac{di}{dt}=V$ and $Vi$ is power.

I understand that since the power is equal to both of these equations that they are equal to each other. The part that I don't get is mathematically how to get from one to the other.

Comment: What happens if you do the derivative in your first expression?

Answer (score 1):

> The part that I don't get is mathematically how to get from one to the
>   other.

$$\frac{d}{dt}U_L(t) = p_L(t) = v_L(t) \cdot i_L(t) = L \cdot i(t) \cdot \frac{di}{dt}$$

but

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left\{\frac{1}{2}Li^2(t)\right\} = L \cdot i(t) \cdot \frac{di}{dt} $$

thus

$$U_L(t) =  \frac{1}{2}Li^2(t)$$